# When is TypeScript top-level non-export code executed?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am currently confused on when code in a file is actually executed an when it is not. If I have a `file1.ts` file like the following:

```
export interface myInterface {}
export function myFunction() {}
export const myConst: {}

// ... and more exports

// top-level non-exported code
if (condition) {
    myConst = ...
}
```

And a `file2.ts` containing one the following:

```
import { myInterface } from "./file1.ts"
```

```
import * from "./file1.ts"
```

```
import * as file1 from "./file1.ts"
```

```
import "./file1.ts"
```

How does the the behaviour differ? When is the **top-level code** that wasn't exported in `file1.ts` executed and when is it not executed? Is it executed even when only a specific export is imported (see first variant)?

This is making me crazy right now and I didn't find anything about it on the [TypeScript handbook page for modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

Comment: When you import the file for the first time, it runs the top level code and returns the exports. If you are using CommonJS, [check this guide](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/)

Comment: @ranisalt, does this mean even when I only import a single export (like in variant 1) all the top-level code is executed?

Comment: As a word of advice, try to have as little top-level code execution with side effects as possible. As @ranisalt describes, it all gets executed on the first import of the file even if you are only importing one element. Speaking from experience, it can throw a monkey wrench in the wheels when you are importing a file only to have a whole bunch of side effects happening, that were not expected.

Comment: @LeonTepe exactly. I suggest you avoid these constructs when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple conditions determine if TypeScript module gets included in final, transpiled JavaScript files, or not:

1. Kind of usage of imported variables in the your own code.
2. Type of imported variables (`class`, `interface`, etc).
3. Since TypeScript 2.8 compiler settings `importsNotUsedAsValues` to control the behavior.
4. Since TypeScript 2.8 there is also new syntax `import type` and `export type` for modules that are explicitly excluded from final, compiled JavaScript files.

Check following section in the TypeScript 2.8 release notes for more details:
[Type-Only Imports and Export](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#-type-only-imports-and-export)